# Batman Arkham City doesn't launch on Windows

Tags: steam, technical-issues, batman-arkham-city

I've just installed Batman: Arkham City GOTY from Steam for the first time. Immediately after launching the game I'm getting a "has stopped working" crash, with the details "APPCRASH" for "BatmanAC.exe". Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

System is a Windows Server on a PC which otherwise matches all the system requirements.

Also, I've found [this Steam forum post which seems to describe the same problem](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2965367).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](http://www.win2008workstation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2046):

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\BatmanAC.exe`

   - If the last entry, `BatmanAC.exe`, doesn't exist, just create it manually
3. Create a new value:

   - Name: `DisableExceptionChainValidation`
   - Type: DWORD
   - Data: 1 (encoding doesn't matter)

Relaunch the game! :)

Comment: I have the same problems, but I have Windows 8. The entry in the file was not successful. Do you have a other solution for it?